# ведомо versus знать

Tags: лексикон

Is there any difference between "мне ведомо" and "я знаю"? Are they interchangeable in any situation? Is "мне ведомо" more formal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

«[не]ведомо» is archaic. People will give you funny looks if you use that word, but they'll understand what you mean.

«[не]известно» is a more modern synonym.

Both options above sound a bit more formal than «я знаю», as is typically the case with passive voice constructs.